# Populate array with a DAO recordset data in VBA MS ACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

**What am I trying to make**

I want a loop which removes the storagelocation of a product if it does not fit in his storagelocation. In this loop I want to save the artikelDetail_ID's in an array. After the loop ends I want to be able to see all the artikelDetail_ID's that got deleted and put into the array during the loop.

When the code runs it'll delete 6 records.

**My solution**

```
Dim verwijderdeID() As Variant
Dim lengte As Integer
lengte = 0
With recordset_opslag_detail_info
    Do Until recordset_opslag_detail_info.EOF
        If (huidige_doos_max_aantal - huidige_doos_inhoud >= 0) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        ReDim verwijderdeID(lengte)
        verwijderdeID(lengte) = recordset_opslag_detail_info!ArtikelDetail_ID
        lengte = lengte + 1
        huidige_doos_inhoud = huidige_doos_inhoud - recordset_opslag_detail_info!Voorraadperartikel
        .Edit
        !tmea_opslag_locatie = Null
        .Update
        recordset_opslag_detail_info.MoveNext
    Loop
    End With

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(verwijderdeID)
    MsgBox verwijderdeID(i)
Next
```

**Problem**

When my code finds more then one record it'll only safe the last record in the array. If I as per example try to populate the array with 6 values from the recordset only verwijderID(5) will have a value.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible in VBA?

Comment: `Redim` deletes values in an array, `Redim Preserve` keeps the values. I think that should solve your problem. Some extra info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement

Comment: @Beek Good catch.

Comment: @Beek It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `Redim Preserve` with a continually increasing array is an antipattern. It will be a lot slower than necessary, since it will reallocate and copy the array for each iteration. Use a `Collection` instead, which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: If my datasets are always less then 10 records. Will there be big time advantage if I use `Collection`instead of `ReDim`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Redim Preserve` when the array you are changing the size of contains data you want to keep.

`Redim` on it's own will also change the size but it will also wipe all data in the array.

You can read more about it [**here.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement)

---

Following this you want to change your line:

```
ReDim verwijderdeID(lengte)
```

to

```
ReDim Preserve verwijderdeID(lengte)
```